# funçao ajax nao funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou a usar esta pequena funçao para executar meus ajax sem mimimi, veja

```
var HTTP = 'http://127.0.0.1/';
function ajax(to, data) {
       $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: (HTTP + to),
data: data, 
cache: false,
success: function(output) {
alert(output);
}
});
    return false;
};
ajax('ds', null);
```

mas ele nao é executado com sucesso nem ocorre agua, o problema está na URL mas nao sei como resolver :/

Comment: No firefox abra a opção inspecionar elemento `(Ctrl+Shift+i)` -> `Console` -> desmarque tudo e deixe apenas `rede` e `js` ativado. Atualize a pagina e execute a funcionalidade que requisita o ajax.

Comment: Faça os testes no console. veja se há algo na sintaxe.

Comment: @LuanFagundes nao há error :/

Answer (score 1):

Tente remover o http://127.0.0.1 e apenas usar a url relativa, assim:

`var HTTP = '/';` ou `var HTTP = '/index.php';`

## Isso é um bug?

Não, isso ocorre por causa do `CORS`. Essa funcionalidade impede que requisições AJAX sejam feitas para URLs que não sejam do mesmo endereço que sua página.

Então, ao usar o `http://` você definiu que não estaria apontando para uma URL no mesmo endereço que o da página (127.0.0.1)

## Como resolvo?

Para as página que forem responder a sua requisição, adicione os **headers** do **CORS**.

Não sei que servidor está usando, mas se tiver suporte a PHP você pode adicionar os *headers* da seguinte maneira no **index.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // Aceitar requisições de qualquer endereço
```

Ou ainda

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: meusite.com"); // Aceitar requisições AJAX de meusite.com
```

## Referência & Mais sobre o assunto

Existem muitas opções para o CORS e por isso não vou citar todas. A minha fonte está abaixo.

**Fonte:** http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ (em *english*)

Comment: Perdao, nao resolve.